# Policy on suspending users

Tags: discussion, policy

We will soon have temporary moderators from within the community, and so I wanted to initiate a discussion on policies for suspension/blocks/bans. Right now I'm thinking mostly of cases where users are posting questions that repeatedly get closed, without appearing to learn from the reasons given for closing. [This discussion on MO](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/417/suspension/) is one example of how to conduct such a policy, and [here's the SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) on the same issue.

My question, specifically: can we list the conditions and procedures that lead up a user suspension ? ideally not just the behavior, but the sequence of warnings etc.

Comment: Is there any way to send a warning to a user? Do the moderators have some special tools that can be used to send messages to users that will be delivered automatically the next time they visit the site?

Comment: really the only way is direct email: which makes using real names far more helpful.

Comment: I think one of the problems is that not everyone has given their email addresses (or real names, or URLs, or any kind of contact information). And I could imagine that the most "problematic" users might be those without contact information. Hence if we try to come up with some procedures for suspensions, it'd be good if they also covered the case of users who can't be contacted.

Comment: Since we want to encourage real names + real contact information anyway, we could make it a policy to email those who have provided contact information a warning before suspension, and those who don't leave contact information don't get that courtesy.

Comment: I'm thinking of something along the lines of what robin suggests

Comment: Is it more fair to not give warnings to users without contact information, or to give them warnings publicly, e.g. as an @reply on a Bad question/answer of theirs?  (By Bad I mean of the type that would eventually lead to suspension, rather than simply a bad question/answer in the general sense.)  If you're using the site you are contactable, but perhaps only through the public forum of the site itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence and procedure is outlined in this blog post:

[**A Day in the Penalty Box**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)